# Increase width of drag handles W10

Tags: windows

Is there a way to increase the width of drag-handles in Win 10 ?

It always takes me aout five attempts to activate the cursor/handle so I can drag the edges of windows to resize them. The divider between the search window and address bar is even worse. Resizing column widths (in "details" view) is pretty painful, too.

I have a high DPI 13" laptop and you have to be within a nanometer of the window edge to get the handle up.   It was the same in Win 8.

thanks

Comment: It looks like this is the closest related answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1758977/how-to-change-border-width-in-ms-windows-to-grab-and-resize-it

Answer (score 1):

Search in your registry for the value

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

double click on `BorderWidth` and increase the negative value, which usually is something like `-13`. You'll might have to test some settings, but a value between `-100`and `-200` should do the job. Maybe even less, according to your preferences.

You might have to restart for the change to be effective.

Answer adapted from [this article](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/how-to-increase-edge-and-corner-grabbing-zone-for-resizing-a-window/)

Comment: this didn't seem to improve the hit handle for the top border, but still trying it out

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yzorg/48a49d8c34b217746388912b30ec3139 - ps1 / PowerShell script uses `-100`

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions to this problem.

Using a larger mouse cursor might help a bit, in
*Control Panel > Mouse > Pointers*.

Changing the border widths could help, but has its gotchas.
You may read about it in the post
[How to change border width in MS Windows to grab and resize it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1758977/how-to-change-border-width-in-ms-windows-to-grab-and-resize-it)

I would counsel rather to use third-party products, some are listed below.
They allow one to move and resize windows, even ones that
have no borders or title.

[**X-Window Manager like dragging and resizing of windows**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2706/X-Window-Manager-like-dragging-and-resizing-of-win)

This old program still works flawlessly. It uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd>
key like this:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd> dragging resizes
  the clicked window
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> dragging moves
  the clicked window

[**Window Manipulator**](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/Window-Manipulator.shtml)

Similar, but uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which is
somewhat more awkward to use.